# Is it possible to programmatically expand references in a JSON schema?

Tags: java, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am receiving JSON payloads and have two things I want to do with them:

1. Validate the payload against a schema
2. Filter out fields not included in the schema

The fields I want to filter aren't invalid, I just want to remove them from the JSON I'm working with (for my use case these are PII that we don't want to store).

I've found [this library that seems to take care of the filtering for us](https://github.com/chathurabuddi/json-schema-filter). The issue I've found is that it doesn't handle references - any objects that have a reference to the object definition don't have data populated when we do the filtering.

[We're using this library for schema validation](https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-schema-validator). I was hoping we might be able to use this library to expand the references in the schema so that we can still use the same filtering library. [This old issue](https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-schema-validator/issues/41) suggests that in a previous version this was possible using a class called `ResolvingSchemaWalker`, but that class has been removed in more recent versions and I haven't been able to figure out how to traverse a schema to resolve references in the more recent versions of the library. The [RefResolver](https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-schema-core/blob/99a7ad669badbd01fa60f9c79978dae8766d1c1c/src/main/java/com/github/fge/jsonschema/core/load/RefResolver.java) class seems to do something similar, but it adds a `JsonPointer` that references the object definition rather than replacing the reference with the actual JSON object.

If I need to I might edit my schema manually to remove all the references, but I'd like to avoid that if I can. **Is what I want to do with replacing references in the schema possible programmatically?** Based on that old issue I found in the json-schema-validator library it seems like it should be and the `RefResolver` in the current version of the library seems to be doing most of what I'm looking for, but I haven't been able to figure out how to use it to expand those references in the schema.

If someone can point me to a different filtering library that handles references, that could resolve the issue as well. We're not tied to using this filtering library, but it's the best option I've been able to find and seems to do everything we want apart from the issue with references.

Comment: Did you think about deserializing the json? [Jackson](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind) can validate json & de-/serialize from/to POJOs. It can also ignore unknown fields. Is this applicable for your use-case, if no, why not?

Comment: @RatzzFatzz that's what we are doing now and I'm exploring if we can get away from that. All we're doing is consuming this JSON, validating and filtering it, then writing it to an S3 bucket as JSON - so the only thing the POJOs would be used for is the filtering. If we're able to validate and filter using the schema directly, we could pass the schema as a configuration and avoid having to re-deploy with re-generated POJO's if the schema changed. Having generated POJOs definitely makes the filtering easier though, so we may just stick with that if I can't find an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to remove all external references (references to other schema documents). This is generally referred to a schema bundling. However, it's not always possible to remove all local references (references within the same schema document like to `$defs`/`definitions`).

Bundling is actually really easy. Here are some references.

- https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html#bundling
- https://json-schema.org/blog/posts/bundling-json-schema-compound-documents

Inlining local references ranges from trivial to hard to impossible. If there are no references in the sub-schema being inlined, then a simple replacement can work. If the sub-schema being inlined has references, you might have to rewrite those references because their target might have been moved as well. If the schema is recursive, the fully inlined schema would be infinitely large. Of course you could limit the recursion depth and only have a very large schema instead of an infinitely large schema.

So, if your tooling doesn't handle local references, it's pretty much useless and there's not much you can do. If your tooling just doesn't handle external references, that shouldn't be a problem. It's easy enough to bundle a schema by hand. You don't even need additional tooling.

Comment: The schema we're working with right now has references in the sub-schema, but there's nowhere in the schema where the references go more than three layers deep. If this schema is not recursive, it sounds like inlining the local references should be doable?

Comment: Yes, if there's no recursion, it should be doable. Whether it's trivial or hard depends on the those references. It's worth giving it try by hand and seeing how it goes.

Comment: When you say "by hand", do you mean manually replacing the references in the schema to re-structure it? Or writing my own schema walker that finds the local references and inlines them? I've been trying to write a schema walker, but I'm having a hard time with it.

Comment: Yes, I meant manually copy/paste move schemas around. Automating it would be a lot harder.